# iOS UITableView reloadData only updates the last entry I added, how do I reload everything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The actual issue is that the data I am getting is from an NSSet and when I change the set, since it is unordered, the final entry is not always the same or the last object I added to the set.  So, when I call reloadData (and with a breakpoint I can tell it is only updating/adding the last cell in the table because the number of rows has increased by 1) it often finds the wrong entry to add to the new cell and I end up with duplicates and with my new object not appearing in the table.

Is this the correct behavior for reloadData?  And if so, what should I be using instead to make sure all the data appears?  Should I just delete all the rows and start over or is there a way to just update the properties of the rows already there?

Edit: I suppose I was unclear, prior to feeding the data to the tableView, I convert it to an array but the array is never in the same order due to the nature of a set.  It was suggested that I order the array but even if I did that, the new item would not appear if it was not the last item in the order.

Comment: How many cells are visible on screen at once?

Comment: You basically answered the question yourself. A set can't be used as a dataSource because it's unordered. Convert your set to an ordered collection by sorting it.

Comment: I convert it to an Array before giving it to the tableView but I suppose you are correct that if i ordered the array it may solve the problem.  However, is this the correct behavior of reloadData?  because even if i ordered the array, if the new item fell in the middle of the order, it still would not show up since reloadData is only updating the last item.

Comment: Is your breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  ReloadData will trigger that method only for cells that are visible.  Hence my question above: if you have only one visible cell, it will be called only once.

Comment: oh, sorry, yes my breakpoint is in that method, however, there are about 10 items visible at a time and this same behavior is seen whether there are 5 items, 10 items or 20 items in the table.

Comment: Hmm, very odd.  The whole point of reloadData is that it does force the tableView to rebuild from scratch.  So, if you sort your array and call reloadData, you will be doing the right things.  Are you sure that reloadData is being executed?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use an `NSSet` to feed a `UITableView`. Since `NSSet`is not ordered with indexes, `UITableView` won't behave properly. Try to switch to `NSArray` which has object indexes.